# Querying an array using Go and Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I have the following scenario:

```
type Band struct {
    Name       string
    LocationId *datastore.Key
    Albums     []Album
}

type Album struct {
    Name    string
    GenreId *datastore.Key
    Year    int
}
```

What I want to do is query a `Band`s `Albums` key for an album with a specific `GenreId` key.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. It turned out to be simple. Instead of

```
Filter("GenreId =", genreId)
```

I used

```
Filter("Albums.GenreId =", genreId)
```

That gave me valid query results.

Comment: Usually the Filter works without the need of specifying the "entity kind", you might want to check if config.BAND_TYPE is empty which can cause the query to run as a "kindless query" (query against all kind)

Comment: BAND_TYPE is defined as follows

const BAND_TYPE = "Band"

in dataconfig.go

Comment: If you read my code at the top, you will see that GenreId is stored in an array of albums.